# Conditionally find percent of occurrences in field 2, given field 1 in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am running Windows 10, Python 2.7 through the Spyder IDE.

I have a pandas `DataFrame` called `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': ['x', 'x', 'x','x','y','y','y','z','z']
                , 'fld2': ['a', 'b', 'c','c','a','b','c','a','b']})

>>> df
fld1 fld2
0    x    a
1    x    b
2    x    c
3    x    c
4    y    a
5    y    b
6    y    c
7    z    a
8    z    b
```

I would like to calculate the percent of `fld2` that make up `fld1` and save that percentage in `fld3` so that the product is unique combinations of `fld1` and `fld2`. The product of this code should look like `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': ['x', 'x', 'x','y','y','y','z','z']
                , 'fld2': ['a', 'b', 'c','a','b','c','a','b']
                , 'fld3': [.25,.25,.50,.33,.33,.33,.5,.5]})
>>> df2
fld1 fld2  fld3
0    x    a  0.25
1    x    b  0.25
2    x    c  0.50
3    y    a  0.33
4    y    b  0.33
5    y    c  0.33
6    z    a  0.50
7    z    b  0.50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.size.html) and divide by sums created by[`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
print df

  fld1 fld2
0    x    a
1    x    b
2    x    c
3    x    c
4    y    a
5    y    b
6    y    c
7    z    a
8    z    b
```

```
g = df.groupby(['fld1', 'fld2'])['fld1'].size()
print g

fld1  fld2
x     a       1
      b       1
      c       2
y     a       1
      b       1
      c       1
z     a       1
      b       1
dtype: int64

print g / g.groupby(level=0).transform(sum)

fld1  fld2
x     a       0.250000
      b       0.250000
      c       0.500000
y     a       0.333333
      b       0.333333
      c       0.333333
z     a       0.500000
      b       0.500000
dtype: float64
```